# Can I instruct ispell to insert LocalWords in a different file?

Tags: ispell, spell-checking

Sometimes my `LocalWords` can get very long.  In Org documents, it's awkward to have this 'appendix' of dictionary junk.  I'd like to move this to a separate file (`.dir-locals.el` if possible).

Comment: This has been on my todo-list for a couple of years -- I'm looking forward to trying out your solution.

Comment: @lawlist you may then be interested in [these functions](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31419/2264) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ispell-buffer-session-localwords` for this purpose.  In your `.dir-locals.el`, configure the variable for `org-mode` as follows:

```lisp
((org-mode
  (ispell-buffer-session-localwords
   "my" "special" "words" "here")))
```