# How can I move all my file-local LocalWords to .dir-locals.el?

Tags: ispell, spell-checking

This is a follow-up question to [Can I instruct ispell to insert LocalWords in a different file?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31396/2264).

So now that I've got a way to use a separate file for my local dictionary, is there any way to move the words in my file to `.dir-locals.el` automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take these functions out for a spin and use `M-x *-ispell-move-buffer-words-to-dir-locals`:

```lisp
;; Adapted from ispell.el:ispell-buffer-local-words
(defun *-ispell-buffer-local-words-list ()
  (let (words)
    (or ispell-buffer-local-name
        (setq ispell-buffer-local-name (buffer-name)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward ispell-words-keyword nil t)
        (let ((end (point-at-eol))
              (ispell-casechars (ispell-get-casechars))
              string)
          (while (re-search-forward " *\\([^ ]+\\)" end t)
            (setq string (match-string-no-properties 1))
            (if (and (< 1 (length string))
                     (equal 0 (string-match ispell-casechars string)))
                (push string words))))))
    words))

(defun *-ispell-move-buffer-words-to-dir-locals ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (buffer-file-name)
    (user-error "buffer not attached to file"))
  (let ((words (*-ispell-buffer-local-words-list)))
    (save-excursion
      (add-dir-local-variable
       major-mode
       'ispell-buffer-session-localwords
       (setq ispell-buffer-session-localwords
             (cl-remove-duplicates
              (append ispell-buffer-session-localwords words)
              :test #'string=)))
      (when (y-or-n-p "Save .dir-locals.el?")
        (save-buffer))
      (bury-buffer))
    (or ispell-buffer-local-name
        (setq ispell-buffer-local-name (buffer-name)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward ispell-words-keyword nil t)
        (delete-region (point-at-bol) (1+ (point-at-eol)))))))
```

This solution won't limit your dictionary to a single file, though; changes will apply to all buffers of the same major mode.