# Marking as safe all possible lists of strings

Tags: variables, list, string, ispell, directory-local-variables

Following [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31397/16781), I put the following lines in a `.dir-locals.el` file:

```
((latex-mode
  (TeX-engine . default)
  (mode . latex )
  (TeX-master . "main")
  (ispell-buffer-session-localwords
   "TODO" "SDP" "MDPC" "GJE" "fpc" "QGJE" "GJI" "QGJI" "Bachmann" "Varshamov"))
```

However, each time I open a new file, I get a prompt asking to confirm if the values in the `ispell-buffer-session-localwords` are safe or not. Is there any way to specify that *all the possible strings* are safe values for this variable? Are there any cons in doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)File Local Variables` says:

> You can specify safe values for a variable with a
> ‘safe-local-variable’ property.  The property has to be a function of
> one argument; any value is safe if the function returns non-‘nil’ given
> that value.  Many commonly-encountered file variables have
> ‘safe-local-variable’ properties; these include ‘fill-column’,
> ‘fill-prefix’, and ‘indent-tabs-mode’.  For boolean-valued variables
> that are safe, use ‘booleanp’ as the property value.

In your case you could do this:

```el
(defun list-of-strings-p (list)
  "Non-nil if LIST is a list of strings."
  (not (catch 'non-string
         (dolist (x list nil)
           (unless (stringp x)
             (throw 'non-string t))))))

(put 'ispell-buffer-session-localwords 'safe-local-variable
     'list-of-strings-p)
```

Answer (score 0):

To mark as safe for the variables you know they are safe,

```lisp
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook (lambda () (setq enable-local-variables :safe)))
```

But in your case, it looks like you have to use `:all` instead of `:safe`.

Emacs manual: [Safety of File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html)

Comment: But this will mark ALL the variables as safe, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it is limited to variables defined for `latex-mode` by the `add-hook`

Comment: `enable-local-variables` is *not* automatically buffer-local.  You are setting the global value for every buffer as soon as any latex file is visited.

Comment: @phils I actually tried it and it only worked in `latex-mode` and the prompt still appears at the other modes. Why does it seem to be working as expected?

Comment: Ah, yes I was wrong about it setting the global value -- it looks like this variable is `let`-bound when the major mode hook runs, so your hook function only modifies that temporary value, and the original value is restored soon afterwards.

Comment: That said, I still wouldn't really recommend this approach -- telling Emacs that *all* local variable values are safe just so long as the buffer is in `latex-mode` means that a .tex file with a malicious local variables setting can do undesirable things.  (And as unlikely as that scenario might be, I think it's preferable not to configure that unnecessarily.)

Comment: @phils Roger. Certainly, we don't know the degree of risk in a situation where all inputs(opportunity to open other people's TeX source, etc) are not fully defined.